# testdriven.io Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker / why os.environ.get instead of using get_settings()?

Tags: testdriven.io

I am at https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-fastapi/postgres-setup/#H-1-tortoise-orm right now.. and I see that `os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")` is used in the `register_tortoise` call:

```
register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"),
    modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)
```

Has anybody wondered: why not make use of `get_settings`, since (a) it is already available (`from app.config import get_settings, Settings`), and (b) `get_settings` is already decorated with `@lru_cache`, so it is not a concern calling it?